# CakePHP 2 save data from JSON request

Tags: json, save, cakephp-2.0

The form was created automagicly by CakePHP FormHelper, and request was created like that:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: _url,
        data: JSON.stringify( $("form").serializeArray() ),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

In controller I add this line to get proper JSON data:

```
$this->RequestHandler->addInputType('json', array('json_decode', true));
```

but its is not proper, because I can't put it into model save method

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => _method
            [value] => POST
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => data[ModelName][fieldname]
            [value] => value of this field
        )

)
```

How to get right data from JSON request ?

Comment: Your application should be able to receive the data as normal with `$this->request->data`

Answer (score 0):

Your json request send to controller action as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: _url,
    data: JSON.stringify( $("form").serializeArray() ),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Get the response in the controller action as below:

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()){

    // "spit" out json re
    echo $this->request->data;

    //decode data into an array
    $decodedData = json_decode($this->request->data);

    // You can check your data before saving...
    //pr($decodedData); die();

    //standard saving code would be
    $this->Model->save($decodedData);
}
```

Please try above logic and let me know.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this is not the solution. Because data in post request is formatted in different way:

```
{"name": "data[FieldName]", "value": "testvalue"}
```